# Cassandra QueryBuilder not returning any result, whereas same query works fine in CQL shell

Tags: cassandra, cql3, cassandra-3.0

```
SELECT count(*) FROM device_stats    
WHERE orgid = 'XYZ'     
AND regionid = 'NY'     
AND campusid = 'C1'     
AND buildingid = 'C1'
AND floorid = '2'      
AND year = 2017;
```

The above CQL query returns **correct result - 32032, in CQL Shell**

But when I run the same query using QueryBuilder Java API , **I see the count as 0**

---

```
BuiltStatement summaryQuery = QueryBuilder.select()
                .countAll()
                .from("device_stats")
                .where(eq("orgid", "XYZ"))
                .and(eq("regionid", "NY"))
                .and(eq("campusid", "C1"))
                .and(eq("buildingid", "C1"))
                .and(eq("floorid", "2"))
                .and(eq("year", "2017"));
        try {
        ResultSetFuture tagSummaryResults = session.executeAsync(tagSummaryQuery);

        tagSummaryResults.getUninterruptibly().all().stream().forEach(result -> {
            System.out.println(" totalCount > "+result.getLong(0));
```

});

---

I have only 20 partitions and 32032 rows per partition.

**What could be the reason QueryBuilder not executing the query correctly ?**

---

Schema :

```
CREATE TABLE device_stats (
    orgid  text,
    regionid text, 
    campusid text, 
    buildingid text,
    floorid text,
    year int,
    endofwindow timestamp,
    categoryid timeuuid,
    devicestats map<text,bigint>,
    PRIMARY KEY ((orgid, regionid, campusid, buildingid, floorid,year),endofwindow,categoryid)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (endofwindow DESC,categoryid ASC);

// Using the keys function to index the map keys
CREATE INDEX ON device_stats (keys(devicestats));
```

---

I am using **cassandra 3.10 and com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:3.1.4**

Comment: Can you change `.and(eq("year", "2017"))` to `.and(eq("year", 2017))` and see if that works?

Comment: awesome :-) .. worked like a charm

Comment: quick question on the query    **if I want to check ~ categoryid IN (c1,c2,c3) , should I use an UDF** as clustering key constraint not allowing me to check if categoryid belongs to a range of values.

Comment: using allowFiltering() after from(..) clause, I could use in clause in last clustering cloumn

Comment: If you use `allowFiltering()` then just keep in mind that your query might end up being not efficient

Comment: I moved my comment to an official answer. Can you mark it since it solved your original problem?

Answer (score 1):

*Moving my comment to an answer since that seems to solve the original problem:*

Changing `.and(eq("year", "2017"))` to `.and(eq("year", 2017))` solves the issue since `year` is an `int` and not a `text`.